# How did the spelling "demesne" come about?

Tags: etymology, orthography

The word *demesne* seems to just be an alternative spelling of the rather more logically-spelt *domain*.  I'm wondering how this strange spelling came about?  Even taking into account its given etymology from the Old French *demein*, how did the letter "s" get in there?

Comment: general reference http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=demesne

Comment: @mplungjan It doesn't say much beyond ".. fondness for inserting -*s*- before -*n*- ... "

Comment: _Re-spelled by Anglo-French legal scribes under influence of Old French mesnie "household"_ Seeing the actual answers it is still GR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OED has this in its etymology (this is an extract):

> The Anglo-Norman spelling *demesne* of the law-books, and 17th cent. legal antiquaries, was partly merely graphic (the quiescence of original *s* before a consonant leading to the insertion of a non-etymological *s* to indicate a long vowel), as in *mesne* = Old French *meien, meen, mean,* modern French *moyen;* partly perhaps influenced by association with *mesne* itself, in ‘mesne lord’, or with *mesnie < mansionāta* house, household establishment. Demesne land was apparently viewed by some as *terra mansionatica,* land attached to the mansion or supporting the owner and his household. Perhaps also Bracton's words [below] gave the notion that the word has some connection with *mensa.*
>
> [c1250   Bracton iv. iii. ix. §5   Est autem Dominicum, quod quis habet ad mensam suam & proprie, sicut sunt Bordlands Anglice. Item dicitur Dominicum Villenagium, quod traditur villanis, quod quis tempestivè & intempestivè sumere possit pro voluntate sua & revocare.]

So: a long vowel (the second e) was indicated in spelling by inserting an s.

OED does use the word "Perhaps", but it does seem to me to be a bit far-fetched to think that people confused *mensa* and *mesne*.

Comment: The legal antiquaries had here the testimony of an eminent jurist that a property is *dominicum*, of the domain, **because** it is held to one's own *mensa*, 'table' or 'board', as evidenced by the fact that such properties are called in English *bordlands*. Even if a reading were not strictly true, that it had been *held* to be true would carry great weight with scholars whose guiding authority was precedent. And the etymology is not entirely unreasonable two hundred years before such resources as the OED were available.

Answer (score 1):

> c.1300, demeyne (modern spelling by late 15c.), [snip] Old French demaine "land held for a lord's own use," from Latin dominicus "belonging to a master," [snip] Re-spelled by Anglo-French legal scribes under influence of Old French mesnie "household" (and the concept of a demesne as "land attached to a mansion") and their fondness for inserting -s- before -n-. [snip]

Source: http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=demesne